# Javascript / Jquery get() won't work on mobile browsers (calling node-red, node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, node-red

I've been hacking round for about a week trying to work this out, so finally cracked and asked a question:

My setup is Raspberry Pi 2 running Apache and IBM's Node-Red. I'm using Apache to serve up a simple web page which calls Node-Red to kick off a flow (in this case it's to switch on and off lights via Open Zwave.)

The following solution works on desktop browsers (firefox / IE 11) but not on mobile browsers (IE on WP8.1 and Android browser). However the code triggers the "Alert" from mobile browsers, just not the `$.get()` Any ideas?

Note that I've used two different methods of calling the target, one proper `JSON`, the other just a string. Both work on desktop browsers, both fail mobile browsers.

Header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=11; IE=edge"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Script Section:

```
 <script>

// Wait until the page is loaded so that all the IDs are setup
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').click(function(){ 
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'node-3-on':
            $.get("http://node-red:1880/setValueBinary.html", {nodeid:"3", value:"1"});
            alert ("node 3 on");
            break;
        case 'node-3-off':
            // alert ("node 3 off");
            $.get('http://node-red:1880/setValueBinary.html?nodeid=3&value=0');
            break;
// removed further case statements
            default:
            alert ("You shouldn't see this, some sort of error has happened.");
            };
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p><b>Switch 3:</b></p>
<p> <img src="images/green-tick.png" id="node-3-on" alt="Switch On" height="100" width="100" />
    <img src="images/red-cross.png" id="node-3-off" alt="Switch Off" width="100" height="100"/></p>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what's going on. It triggers an alert, but which one? The `node 3 on` or the `You shouldn't see this`? Besides, you're making a $get call, but you're doing nothing with it (there are no callbacks, so nothing happens in return). What are you excpecting this code to do? EDIT : Okay, I got it. Gonna make a proper answer.

Comment: In the first case of the switch statement there is an "alert" after the get(), this triggers on any browser mobile or desktop.The idea is that nothing is done with the get, at the browser side, it's just being used to trigger a flow in Node-Red, with a couple of bits of data specifying what to do.

Comment: So how do you know the $get is not made? Try alerting something in a callback

Comment: I know that the $get is not made as nothing happens on the node-red debug console, however it does with desktop browsers.

Comment: So what does the callback alert output?

Comment: If I change the get() line to: "$.get("http://node-red:1880/setValueBinary.html", {nodeid:"3", value:"1"}, function(){alert ("made get");});" It doesn't make the alert, on either desktop or mobile, however it still makes the call on desktop, but not mobile. However, the Node-Red side seems to be complaining about CORS.

Comment: When I try to reach `http://node-red:1880/setValueBinary.html` in Chrome, it fails and says : DNS name could not be resolved, server unreachable. I should have started here.

Comment: Node-Red is the (changed to make it clearer) name of my Raspberry Pi, it's all internal.

Comment: try `$.get(...).error( function(err){ alert(err); } )`

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of a workmate I installed Chrome and set it up to do remote debug on my Android phone.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

It turns out that the problem was that for some reason desktop/laptop/tablet devices can resolve the shortname of the raspberry pi, however mobile phones can't. This is using the same DHCP and DNS servers. I went through the code and added FQDNs to all the URLs and it all works fine now.

I'm sort of glad and sort of livid.

Thanks all for your help.